# Error Tracing in PHP MYSQL- Is there more info?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am trying to implement user registration for a website.
All is well, until I get this in the error log on the server:

> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/yclyxfu6ktu0/public_html/mydomain.com/newapp/register.php(50): PDOStatement->fetchAll()
> #1 {main}
> thrown in /home/yclyxfu6ktu0/public_html/mydomain.com/newapp/register.php on line 50

So, I go to line 50 in *register.php*.

```
00000001 <?php
00000002 //register.php
00000003 
00000004 include('database_connection.php');
00000005 
00000006 if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
00000007 {
00000008  header("location:index.php");
00000009 }
00000010 
00000011 $message = '';
00000012 
00000013 if(isset($_POST["register"]))
00000014 {
00000015  $query = "
00000016  SELECT * FROM register_user 
00000017  WHERE user_email = :user_email
00000018  ";
00000019  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
00000020  $statement->execute(
00000021   array(
00000022    ':user_email' => $_POST['user_email']
00000023   )
00000024  );
00000025  $no_of_row = $statement->rowCount();
00000026  if($no_of_row > 0)
00000027  {
00000028   $message = '<label class="text-danger">Email Already Exits</label>';
00000029  }
00000030  else
00000031  {
00000032   $user_password = rand(100000,999999);
00000033   $user_encrypted_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
00000034   $user_activation_code = md5(rand());
00000035   $insert_query = "
00000036   INSERT INTO register_user 
00000037   (user_name, user_email, user_password, user_activation_code, user_email_status) 
00000038   VALUES (:user_name, :user_email, :user_password, :user_activation_code, :user_email_status)
00000039   ";
00000040   $statement = $connect->prepare($insert_query);
00000041   $statement->execute(
00000042    array(
00000043     ':user_name'   => $_POST['user_name'],
00000044     ':user_email'   => $_POST['user_email'],
00000045     ':user_password'  => $user_encrypted_password,
00000046     ':user_activation_code' => $user_activation_code,
00000047     ':user_email_status' => 'not verified'
00000048    )
00000049   );
00000050   $result = $statement->fetch();
00000051   if(isset($result))
00000052   {
00000053    $base_url = "http://everyonehr/newapp/";
00000054    $mail_body = "
00000055    <p>Hi ".$_POST['user_name'].",</p>
00000056    <p>Thanks for Registration. Your password is ".$user_password.", This password will work only after your email verification.</p>
00000057    <p>Please Open this link to verified your email address - ".$base_url."email_verification.php?activation_code=".$user_activation_code."
00000058    <p>Best Regards,<br />Webslesson</p>
00000059    ";
00000060    require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
00000061    $mail = new PHPMailer;
00000062    $mail->IsSMTP();        //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
00000063    $mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';  //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
00000064    $mail->Port = '80';        //Sets the default SMTP server port
00000065    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;       //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
00000066    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxx';     //Sets SMTP username
00000067    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';     //Sets SMTP password
00000068    $mail->SMTPSecure = '';       //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
00000069    $mail->From = 'info@webslesson.info';   //Sets the From email address for the message
00000070    $mail->FromName = 'Webslesson';     //Sets the From name of the message
00000071    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name']);  //Adds a "To" address   
00000072    $mail->WordWrap = 50;       //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
00000073    $mail->IsHTML(true);       //Sets message type to HTML    
00000074    $mail->Subject = 'Email Verification';   //Sets the Subject of the message
00000075    $mail->Body = $mail_body;       //An HTML or plain text message body
00000076    if($mail->Send())        //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
00000077    {
00000078     $message = '<label class="text-success">Register Done, Please check your mail.</label>';
00000079    }
00000080   }
00000081  }
00000082 }
00000083 
00000084 ?>
00000085 
00000086 <!DOCTYPE html>
00000087 <html>
00000088  <head>
00000089   <title>PHP Register Login Script with Email Verification</title>  
00000090   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
00000091   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
00000092   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
00000093  </head>
00000094  <body>
00000095   <br />
00000096   <div class="container" style="width:100%; max-width:600px">
00000097    <h2 align="center">PHP Register Login Script with Email Verification</h2>
00000098    <br />
00000099    <div class="panel panel-default">
00000100     <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Register</h4></div>
00000101     <div class="panel-body">
00000102      <form method="post" id="register_form">
00000103       <?php echo $message; ?>
00000104       <div class="form-group">
00000105        <label>User Name</label>
00000106        <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required />
00000107       </div>
00000108       <div class="form-group">
00000109        <label>User Email</label>
00000110        <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" required />
00000111       </div>
00000112       <div class="form-group">
00000113        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" class="btn btn-info" />
00000114       </div>
00000115      </form>
00000116      <p align="right"><a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
00000117     </div>
00000118    </div>
00000119   </div>
00000120  </body>
00000121 </html>
```

The new user information gets inserted into the database, so I know the database connection works.
Can anyone tell me why the script fails here:

```
00000050   $result = $statement->fetch();
```

Thank you in advance!
I simply can't figure out what's wrong with the statement.

Comment: You can only use `fetchAll()` with queries that return rows, such as `SELECT`. `INSERT` doesn't return anything to fetch.

Comment: @Barmar I edited the question. I am using fetch() but I also tried fetchAll(). No Joy!!! I think the code is meant to grab that new user's details, and the password information tcreated for that record in the database, then mail it ot the new user for verification - if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use fetch or fetchall. What are you trying to fetch?

Comment: The details are all in the variables that you used in the query, you don't need to fetch anything from the DB.

Comment: You never use `$result`, why do you need to set it?

Comment: @Barmar - I think you are on to it. For some reason the orginal coder, has this line of code, but upon closer examination - it doesn't seem needed. I think perhaps he or she wanted to make sure these variables were set before traying to send mail, but...if the database insert is successful, they must be set. Thank you for sticking with me!! Still learning.

Comment: There's something wrong in your logging code if you only get a stack trace but not the actual error. You can eventually guess what's wrong but it's easier if you just let PHP tell you.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` queries don't return any results, so you can't fetch them.

If you want to know if the `INSERT` was successful, check the return value of `execute()`.

```
if ($statement->execute(...)) {
    // code that sends mail
} else {
    // report failure
}
```

Comment: So, the database record is definitely updated, but the mail doesn't seem to send...localhost, but on GoDaddy....no error indicated....I just don't know how to diagnose the problems.

Comment: That's a completely different problem.

Comment: @DavidWeisser "no error indicated" - As I said, that's the big problem here. You can guess your way through bugs but it'd be easier if your error logging code didn't strip the most vital information it's expected to provide.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - I agree with you. "it'd be easier if your error logging code didn't strip the most vital information it's expected to provide" <- I don't know how to accomplish this yet. I need to investigate ways to better debug code - the subject of another post search. Thank you!!

Comment: Use `try/catch` and in the catch block print `$error->getMessage()`. It will show the MySQL error.

Comment: Builtin error logging doesn't strip the error message. You must have custom code doing so.

Comment: Right. `{main} thrown in ...` doesn't look like the error that would be reported by the default error handler. It would be something like `PDOException thrown` and it will include the MySQL error details.